# displaying something depending on the content I get back from a loop PHP & Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a BuddyDev plugin with a customizable template to display a set of users on my home page. I want to display something under their names for each name differently. But since it's not built into their core plugin, I'm trying to add it by searching for their name first.

This is how I get their names `<?php bp_member_name(); ?>`, I want to implement something like this

```
<?php if( strpos( bp_member_name(), 'Casey Jordan' ) !== false ) : ?>
   <p>Technician</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( strpos( bp_member_name(), 'John Doe' ) !== false ) : ?>
   <p>Manager</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( strpos( bp_member_name(), 'Mary Poppins' ) !== false ) : ?>
   <p>Secretary</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and so on. Essentially something more programmatic than that would be perfect too, but I'd be happy with a if-elseif or a switch statement. I'm just not very good in PHP.

Right now, this is not returning anything at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess `bp_member_name()` will `echo` the string. Try with `bp_get_member_name()` instead.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: No problem @LOTUSMS , I wrote an answer for this.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I want to give you the answer credit, but the other answer is much cleaner in switch statement. If you have a better programmatic way to write it, I'll give you the answer credit since you solved the main problem first. Otherwise, future users will probably upovote his answer anyway. So it's up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch would be a good choice and you only need to retrieve the member name one time so we'll do it before the switch.

```
$member_name = bp_get_member_name();
switch ($member_name) {
    case 'Casey Jordan':
        echo '<p>Technician</p>';
        break;
    case 'John Doe':
        echo '<p>Manager</p>';
        break;
    default:
        echo '<p>Unidentified</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `bp_member_name` will display the name using `echo`.
The function you want, `bp_get_member_name` will `return` the value to some variable that you can use.
So just replace the function:

```
<?php if( strpos( bp_get_member_name(), 'Casey Jordan' ) !== false ) : ?>
   <p>Technician</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( strpos( bp_get_member_name(), 'John Doe' ) !== false ) : ?>
   <p>Manager</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( strpos( bp_get_member_name(), 'Mary Poppins' ) !== false ) : ?>
   <p>Secretary</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```